# How do I configure AD CS to support Name Constraints (4.2.1.11 in RFC 2459)?

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, smartcard, smime

I am trying to figure out how to do [Qualified Subordination](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780153%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) with the [critical extension](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=24) set, but I'm unable to figure out how to do this in MSFT AD CS.

For a given certificate, how do I make sure that the name constraints are set appropriately on the issued cert?

**Edit**

Work done so far  (see edit history for more work done):

I installed a sub CA here [following these directions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737026%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

> The name constraints are configured in one of two locations. When
>   creating a new CA, you can define name constraints for that CA by
>   configuring CAPolicy.inf to impose name constraints. Likewise, if you
>   are creating a qualified subordinate CA certificate, you would define
>   name constraints in the Policy.inf file. In both cases, the following
>   syntax is used:
>
> ```
> [NameConstraintsExtension]
> Include = NameConstraintsPermitted
> Exclude = NameConstraintsExcluded
> Critical = TrUe
>
> [NameConstraintsPermitted]
> DNS = ""
> email=""
> UPN=""
>
> [NameConstraintsExcluded]
> DNS = .nwtraders.com
> email = @nwtraders.com
> UPN = .nwtraders.com
> UPN = @nwtraders.com
> URI = ftp://.nwtraders.com
> DIRECTORYNAME = "DC=NWtraders, DC=com"
> ```

My capolicy.inf on the subCA is this

```
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"

[PolicyStatementExtension]
Policies=LegalPolicy

[LegalPolicy]
OID=1.2.3.4.1455.67.89.5
Notice="Legal Policy Statement"
URL=http://pki.bitclear.us/pki/cps.txt

[Certsrv_Server]
RenewalKeyLength=2048
RenewalValidityPeriod=Years
RenewalValidityPeriodUnits=20
LoadDefaultTemplates=0
AlternateSignatureAlgorithm=1
# ForceUTF8=0 

[CRLDistributionPoint] 
Empty=True

[AuthorityInformationAccess] 
Empty=True

[BasicConstraintsExtension] 
PathLength=1 
Critical=Yes

[NameConstraintsExtension]
Include = NameConstraintsPermitted
Exclude = NameConstraintsExcluded
Critical = True

[NameConstraintsPermitted]
DirectoryName = "DC=gg, DC=Com"
email = @gg.com
UPN = .gg.com
UPN = @gg.com


#[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension] 
#OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4        ; Secure Email 
#OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.2    ; Smart Card Logon 
#Critical=No
# on a sub CA do this: Certutil –setreg Policy\CAPathLength 2
```

my policy.inf on the SubCA and rootCA is this

```
[Version]
Signature= "$Windows NT$"

[RequestAttributes]
CertificateTemplate = SubCA

[PolicyStatementExtension]
Policies = HighAssurancePolicy, MediumAssurancePolicy, LowAssurancePolicy
CRITICAL = FALSE

[HighAssurancePolicy]
OID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.2473717464.1095930238.502626717.506190032.1.402

[MediumAssurancePolicy]
OID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.2473717464.1095930238.502626717.506190032.1.401

[LowAssurancePolicy]
OID = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.2473717464.1095930238.502626717.506190032.1.400

[NameConstraintsExtension]
Include = NameConstraintsPermitted
Exclude = NameConstraintsExcluded
Critical = True

[NameConstraintsPermitted]
DirectoryName = "DC=g, DC=Com"
email = @g.com
UPN = .g.com
UPN = @g.com

[NameConstraintsExcluded]
```

No matter how many times I restart the subCA, or reinstall the subCA, or restart the rootCA I'm unable to get a name restriction visible in the request from the subCA (via certutil - dump) or when I view the certificate that is issued in the MMC.

I know this is possible because a [dump with name constraints is available here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft just posted this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2014/03/05/constraints-what-they-are-and-how-they-re-used-1.aspx) on how to use Name Constraints with AD CS

To apply a name constraint to a pending policy run the following command

```
Certreq -policy originalrequest.req policy.inf modifiedrequest.req
```

`originalrequest.req` – the original request file provided by the subordinate to the parent CA

`policy.inf` - The policy file containing the settings you want to be applied to the request

`modifiedrequest.inf` - This is the output file that will contain the original request and has been modified by the policy.  This file will be supplied to the parent CA instead of the `originalrequest.req`